# Socket server creating empty file

Tags: python

**Problem**

Basically the server socket need to receive the bytes from the client socket and create the file, but when the server socket receive the bytes it don't save the bytes and create an empty file.

**Server**

```
import socket               # Import socket module
s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                 # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
f = open('image.png','wb')
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print('Got connection from', addr)
    print("Receiving...")
    l = c.recv(1024)
    while (l):
        print(l)
        f.write(l)
        l = c.recv(1024)
    f.close()
    print("Done Receiving")
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')
    c.close()                # Close the connection
```

**Client**

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                 # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
s.send(b"Hello server!")
f = open('image.png','rb')
print('Sending...')
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
    print('Sending...')
    s.send(l)
    l = f.read(1024)
f.close()
print("Done Sending")
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

**Question**

What I need to change to the server create the file correctly?

Comment: You cannot save PNG this way. You just open a PNG file as a string.

Comment: So, I was try to use a text file but it still stay creating a empty file...

Comment: strange I tested your script and it could create file and write to it. I just changed paths in client code. Try to comment out in client **c.send('Thank you for connecting')** line. Did that help you?